# Use custom react component in a react form

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to use a [ReactBootstrapSlider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-slider) component as a form control ([react-router-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-form)):

```
import ReactBootstrapSlider from 'react-bootstrap-slider';

<ReactBootstrapSlider
              value={this.state.offer.price}
              step={10}
              min={0}
              max={100}
            />
```

The following is the original code that uses a regular form input of type number for price:

```
import Form from 'react-router-form';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form method="POST" to="/create-offer" dataKey="offer">
          <FormGroup controlId="formControlsPrice">
            <ControlLabel>Price</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="number"
              placeholder="Enter price"
              defaultValue={this.state.offer.price}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <p>
            <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
          </p>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

I would like to replace the standard form control with the slider.
When I replaced the `<FormControl>` component with `<ReactBootstrapSlider>`, the price attribute was not added to the offer object.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you see any error in console ?

Comment: No, there are no errors in comments

Comment: have you imported `ReactBootstrapSlider` component in the file

Comment: Does `state.offer.price` exist (in both files)?